# Can't generate mapping method with no input arguments with Mapstruct

Tags: java, jpa, datamapper, mapstruct

I’m starting my very first steps with Mapstruct mapper. I want to map a JPA data entity class to a DTO class. This is my source class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {
    @Id
    private Long Id;
    private String projectName;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    List<Sprint> sprints;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    List<Epic> epics;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    List<Story> stories;

    public Project(Long id, String projectName, String description) {
        Id = id;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

This is my target class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProjectDTO {
    private Long Id;
    private String projectName;
    private String description;
}
```

The @Data annotation is from Lombok.
I want to make a mapper to map the Project to ProjectDTO, the attributes like sprints, epics, stories SHOULD NOT be included in ProjectDTO. This is my mapper interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface ProjectMapper extends Mapper {

    ProjectMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ProjectMapper.class)

    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDTO(Project project);
}
```

When I try to build it, this  is the error message I got:

> [ERROR] Can't generate mapping method with no input arguments.

I guess it’s related to the missing properties in ProjectDTO, but don’t know to solve it. With the @Mapping, I cannot do it like:

```
@Mapping(source=“sprints”, target= null)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add the '@NoArgConstructor' as well. MapStruct cannot (yet) deal with constructing objects via constructor.  Another option would be using '@Builder' in stead if your objects are truly immutable

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it doesn't work in my case. Some how I found the solution by get the mapper instance in my ProjectServiceImpl constructor. I will put it here also as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not extend the annotation Mapper. It is enough when you just use it at the type declaration level of your interface

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently with springboot
My solution was:

Create a mapper config

```
@org.mapstruct.MapperConfig(
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
        componentModel = "spring"
)
public interface MapperConfig {
}
```

Then use it like this in one of your mapper classes.

```
@Mapper(
        config = MapperConfig.class
)
public abstract class MyClassMapper...
```

Hope it helps someone.